# Use wordpress database for other script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, passwords, decode

My website used to work on wordpress engine but now I'm writing my own script. The problem is that users passwords in wp_users table are encoded in a strange way... Can anyone please tell how should I encode it so that it worked on my new script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "encoded" password is called a hash. Look through the wordpress code where it does the user insert and find how it hashes the password. Use that same type of scheme. It will probably use a salt, I am not familiar with how wordpress does this, but you will need that salt value as well to make an exact match.

EDIT:

Doing some research, you will want to take a look into the wp-includes/pluggable.php file around line 1200. It should have the salt and password generator techniques stored in there (or at least I think, I did not dig too deep into it).

Answer (score 1):

As premiso said its a hash and you can find the class wordpress use here: [Wordpress PasswordHash](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/class-phpass.php). If you review this class you can easily build it into your own script.